# how to return the literal 1 as Maybe Integer?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and having trouble returning literal `1` as `Maybe Integer`

```hs
alwaysOne:: Integer -> Maybe Integer
alwaysOne n = 1
```

raises

```
error:
    • No instance for (Num (Maybe Integer))
        arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1
      In an equation for ‘alwaysOne’: alwaysOne n = 1
   |
14 | alwaysOne n = 1
   |             ^
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Just 1` instead of `1`.

Comment: You can't do that. Are you perhaps accustomed to languages that do this kind of conversion behind the scenes, or that have no type system worth mentioning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> having trouble returning literal `1` as `Maybe Integer`

The `Maybe a` type has two *data constructors*:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

You need to use one of these data constructors if you want to produce a `Maybe Integer` value. What you want is to pass the `1` to the `Just` data constructor:

```
alwaysOne:: Integer -> Maybe Integer
alwaysOne n = Just 1
```

That is, `Just` takes a value of any type and produces a value of `Maybe` parametrized for that type:

```
Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

`a` above is inferred as `Integer` in your case.

Analogously, if you wanted to define `alwaysNothing`:

```
alwaysNothing :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
alwaysNothing _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, technically speaking, make `Maybe a` an instance of `Num` if `a` is an instance of `Num`. But you **should not do that**.

Technically, it is possible with:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

instance Num a => Num (Maybe a) where
    (*) = liftA2 (*)
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    abs = fmap abs
    signum = fmap signum
    negate = fmap negate
    fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
```

This then also allows to write `Just 2 * Just 4` (for `Just 8`) for example, and then you can use `42` to return `Just 42`.

That being said, it would probably only add a lot of confusion. Therefore you just might use:

```
alwaysOne :: Num b => a -> Maybe b
alwaysOne = const (Just 1)
```

Comment: I would rather phrase it like this: “you could **technically speaking** make `Maybe a` an instance of `Num`, but you definitely _should not_ do that”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, updated :)

Comment: It's also unlawful. `Nothing + negate Nothing /= fromInteger 0`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: yes, although I guess a lot of `Num`s are not perfectly lawful. Like a `Double` with `NaN` where `negate (0/0) + (0/0)` is not `fromInteger 0` either. One can actually see the `NaN` to some extent as the `Nothing` in this case I guess.